# Import file bug

Tags: mysql

I am trying to import a table into PHPMyAdmin, my database has 2 tables, one of which is labelled "table 3". When I try to import a database into PHPMyAdmin it doesn't bother to check if a table called "table 3" already exists. So PHPMyAdmin automatically tries to import the file into "table 3" which fails because the database I am uploading has a completely different column count to the existing "table 3".

I was hoping PHPMyAdmin would create "table 4" but it does not. A simple check to see if a table already exists before importing would be a very useful addition to the software. The other tables were imported automatically but I deleted "table 2" as it was incorrect hence the 2 tables and one being called "table 3".

Comment: Are you sure you are in the correct website?

Comment: This seems to be a bug report for a specific piece of software rather than a real question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `drop table if exists mytable` at the beginning of your import file.

Also, you can add the keyword `CASCADE` to previous statement to drop child tables regarding constraints.

Have a look at the doc : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/drop-table.html

Don't know where your import file comes from, but PHPMyAdmin is able to generate export/import files with this statement already embedded.

Edit : I would not consider it as a "bug". PHPMyAdmin runs sql files with sql commands. I would consider writing proper sql scripts instead of consider it as a "bug".